# DataTable DataView - Bit Value in Database

Tags: c#, datatable, bit, dataview

I have read a database table into a DataTable in my C# program, but I am having a few issues assigning the column which contains a bit value to a Boolean.

Here is my code so far:

```
            // Load and Sort Users DataTable
        DataTable datatableUsers = UserMethods.GetUsers().Tables["Users"];
        datatableUsers.DefaultView.Sort = "Name";

        // Filter Based on Search Box
        datatableUsers.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Name LIKE '%" + user + "%' OR Username LIKE '%" + user + "%'"; ;  
        DataView dataviewUsers = datatableUsers.DefaultView;

        // Loop Through Rows and Add UsersGrid to FlowLayoutPael
        foreach (DataRowView datarowviewUsers in dataviewUsers)
        {
            var UsersGrid = new UsersGrid
            {
                ID = (int)datarowviewUsers["ID"],
                Username = datarowviewUsers["Username"].ToString(),
                User = datarowviewUsers["Name"].ToString(),
                Admin = datarowviewUsers["Administrator"].ToString(),
            };
            flowlayoutpanelUsers.Controls.Add(UsersGrid);
            UsersGrid.WasClicked += UsersGrid_WasClicked;
        }
```

At the moment I am converting the Admin ToString and matching on "True" but that is getting very messy and I would prefer to set Admin to type Boolean.  What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the inline if operator. For example:

```
Admin = datarowviewUsers["Administrator"].ToString() == "True" ? true : false
```

Comment: That gives me 2 errors saying: The name 'False' does not exist in the current context, The name 'True' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @hshah I accidentally capitalized True and False.... it should be true and false. Then it should work... I will edit to fix.

Comment: Doh, I should have spotted that too.  Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's returning a bit value so, based on deepee1's answer.

```
Admin = datarowviewUsers["Administrator"].ToString() == "1" ? true : false;
```

Comment: Due to Bit value, datarowviewUsers["Administrator"].ToString() == "1" will NOT work. It should be datarowviewUsers["Administrator"].ToString() == "True" for comparing.